# Display another eval if previous eval is null

Tags: asp.net, null, eval

I have a field where I want to show something. I want to display any value related to that row  and `if else` method becomes pretty long. I tried something like this:

```
<%#Eval("col1")??Eval("Col2")%>
```

It didn't work. Then I tried this:

```
<%#Eval("col1").ToString() ?? Eval("Col2").ToString()%>
```

It didn't work either. Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't convert it to string. Your first line should work (Worked for me):

```
<%# Eval("Col1")??Eval("Col2") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can complete this task by using public method

```
public string bindVal(object myval)
{
if (myval == null)
{
 return "NA value";
}

 return myVal.ToString();
}
```

Label Code:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblmyvalue" Text='<%# testbind(Eval("myvalue1")) %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Or you may use

```
<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("myvalue1").ToString()) ? "NA" : Eval("myvalue1"))%>
```

Comment: I know but it is the long way. Is there a shorter way to coelasce?

Comment: i don`t think  there is a shorter way to achieve this task.i feel it is the preferred way to do it